# Lightinject similar Kernel_ComponentRegistered of Windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, light-inject

I'm following the tutorial [Dependency injection and Unit of Work using Castle](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/543810/Dependency-Injection-and-Unit-Of-Work-using-Castle).
I'm using lightinject in my project, so I'm using ICompositionRoot instead of IWindsorInstaller.

The problem is that I can't find a method similar to Kernel_ComponentRegistered to add the interceptor. How can I do that in lightinject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little difficult to answer without an example to relate my answer to, but if you add the LightInject.Interception package, you will have access to the Intercept method that makes it possible to add the interceptors.

Best regards
Bernhard Richter

Comment: Yes, that worked for me. I uninstalled windsor and installed LightInject.Interception. Thanks for your help Bernhard.